# How to prevent IE8 from caching OpenLayers map data (ASP.Net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, internet-explorer-8, openlayers

I'm working on an OpenLayers based map view using a dynamically generated KML file in C#/ASP.Net. In the code behind file I define query string parameters to the KML file call, which might look like this:

> /layouts/KmlDataGenerator.aspx?vaccination=2&cohort=2003%7c2010&sex=3&xaxis=Kommune&landsdel=100&show=Map&datatype=Vaccination&extendedfilters=False

This url string is inserted in the KmlFileName literal in the OpenLayers js-code below:

```
vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
        projection: wgs84,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        isBaseLayer: false,
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: '<asp:Literal ID="KmlFileName" runat="server"/>',
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true
            })
        })
    });
```

The problem is that IE8 and earlier seems to cache something - I don't know exactly what, but the map never shows up unless I hit CTRL+F5 or manually clear the cache in IE8. The problem is not present in IE9, Firefox or Chrome...

I've tried adding meta tags to prevent browser caching of the page, and I've also tried to add a randomly generated string to the query string of each javascript call, but nothing helps.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the help of a colleague. It turned out that a few lines of javascript code to handle the map projection, had to be moved to the document.ready() function. I wonder why this was only necessary in IE8 and not in other browsers. But anyway, it solved the problem.

Comment: Interesting, what files did you move?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this with the same purpose in a .ashx file:

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
{
    context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    // Execute code 

    context.Response.Write(<content>);
}
```